# how to stop dynamic resizing of the select picker

Tags: php, html, css

this is first screenshot before selecting option in select picker

[image: this is first screenshot before selecting option in select picker]

This is second screenshot after selecting option in select picker

[image: This is second screenshot after selecting option in select picker]

```
 <div class="form-group" >
                          <label>Bank Name :  <span style="color:red; font-weight:bold;">*</span></label>
                        
                        
                          <select name="bank_name" id="bank_name" class="form-control selectpicker " data-live-search="true" tabindex="-98" required" data-width="100%"">
                        <option value=""></option> 
                        <?php ////foreign_relation('accounts_ledger','ledger_id','ledger_name',$bank_name,'1'); ?>
                        
                        <?php 
                        
                            for($Ts = 0; $Ts <= $sLn; $Ts++){
                                ?>
                                <option value="<?=$allLedgerIdArr[$Ts]?>" <?php if($allLedgerIdArr[$Ts]==$bank_name){echo 'selected';} ?>  ><?=$allLedgerNameArr[$Ts]?></option>;
                                <?php
                            }
                        
                        ?>
                        
                        </select>
                        </div>
```

this is the code I am using to design this from. But when I chose an option in select picker the input field dynamically change according to option value length which cause overlapping between table. I tried data-width but it don't work.

Comment: I see you're using `bootstrap` so how about adding the class `w-100` to the input and see if that works.

Answer (score 1):

This is a poor design, there's clearly not enough space to display 4 columns of inputs. Obviously, it's desirable for the select to display the selected value, so change the layout instead, not the input width.